# Device not showing in Android Studio with flutter

Tags: android-studio, flutter

I am trying to get my device to connect to android studio so I can run the app through my phone, but it doesn't show up. I have used flutter doctor and this is the output I get :
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the following for the first error:

1.) Did you run the command it suggested?

```
flutter doctor --android-licenses
```

2.) Upgrade Android Studio

For the connected device error try the following:

1.) Run `flutter devices` this command is used to verify that Flutter recognizes your Android device which should be connected,

2.) Enable Developer mode on your phone and USB debugging on your device

3.) Using a USB cable plug your phone into the computer and if prompted make sure you authenticate your computer to access the device

4.) Try `flutter devices` again and see what happens

Comment: @Joe_A the licence issue is cleared. The only issue is not seeing my device. I am able to access my device elsewhere and developer options is turn on.

Comment: What is the output of flutter devices? does it recognize your device through that command? DId you install the Google USB Driver? I put the link to the flutter.io website [Flutter_link](https://flutter.io/setup-windows/#set-up-your-android-device)

Comment: @Joe_A What do you mean by output of flutter devices? I have installed google USB driver, still doesn't work.

Answer (score 10):

For me, I was able to solve the issue by following this solution

[Solution](https://github.com/flutter/flutter-intellij/issues/2084#issuecomment-414164342)

the solution is all about telling flutter where is android sdk located by running the following command

```
> flutter config --android-sdk <YOUR_SDK_PATH>
```

**I'm using Ubuntu 18**

Comment: This is very correct answer for my case. Thanks.

Comment: you save my time thanks

Answer (score 0):

Get a look in your android device version and install the same in android studio sdk

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was using a Canary version of Android Studio (e.g `Android Studio Bumblebee | 2021.1.1 Canary 2`), so I had to swap to using  `Android Studio Arctic Fox | 2020.3.1 Beta 4`.

If you go into `Preferences` > `Plugins`, you may get the warning:

> Incompatible: requires IDE build 203.7717.56 or older

[image: Warning in Plugins page in Android Studio]